# Jquery Browser Scrolling issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, scrollbar

I want to test if a web page has a vertical scrollbar to add some padding pixel in the bottom of page for the reason to fix the position if a some box in the bottom. The problem is that when i test the height of the document with the height of the window that's returned equal value, also the height of body tag returns 0 (height of body is dynamic not set).Also the functions below not work properly :

```
function hasScroll(el, direction) {
direction = (direction === 'vertical') ? 'scrollTop' : 'scrollLeft';
var result = !! el[direction];
if (!result) {
el[direction] = 1;
result = !!el[direction];
el[direction] = 0;
}
return result;
}
```

and

```
(function($){
$.fn.hasScrollBar = function(){ return this.get(0).scrollHeight > this.innerHeight();}
})(jQuery);
```

the css body is set with :

```
body{
font-family:'DINRegular';
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
font-size:13px;
color:#000;
}
```

that's returned always false although a scroll bar exists in the page.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the vertical scrollbar when the document first loads and then whenever the window is resized. So here's a crude example.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
var hasScrollbar = $('body').outerHeight()+16 > $(window).height();
if(hasScrollbar){ 
$('#message').show();
} else {
$('#message').hide();
};
}); 
$(window).resize(function() {
var hasScrollbar = $('body').outerHeight()+16 > $(window).height();
if(hasScrollbar){ 
$('#message').show();
} else {
$('#message').hide();
};
});
</script>
<div style="width:600px;height:600px;border:1px solid blue;">
test -
<div id="message" style="display:none;">has vertical scrollbar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. i will try that's what you wrote.